# Maximum call stack size exceeded react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { itemid } from '../actions/action';


class DetailPage extends Component{
    componentWillUpdate(){
    this.props.dispatch(itemid([this.props.params.item,`${this.props.params.item}${this.props.params.id}`]))
    }
    render(){
        const { dispatch } = this.props;
        return(
                <div>
                    {this.props.params.id}
                </div>
            )
    }
}
function selectstate(state){
    return{
        state
    }
}
export default connect(selectstate)(DetailPage)
```

//
**{this.props.params.item}**  are from react-router (path('/detail/item/id'))

why my dispatch are Infinite loop until
 error (Maximum call stack size exceeded)

Answer (score 3):

You're firing dispatch on `componentWillUpdate`. So every time you update state, you're updating state again. You should *never* modify state in componentWillUpdate: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillupdate

Incidentally, doing this in `componentWillReceiveProps` will likely do the same thing, since your state, from the redux store, will come in as `props`.

The question is why are you doing the dispatch after updating? Is it because of the function setting state below?

If you're looking to dispatch after setting a particular state, then you can prevent updates except in that state using `shouldComponentUpdate`. But that feels like a side effect in this configuration. I think you're much better off dispatching your event at the same time as you set state, or as a callback to that.